# Can "Can you, please, help me" be followed by "as to which"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Can "Can you, please help me" be followed by "as to which"?

For example,

> Thanks for telling me which button on that website I need to click.
>   Well, I clicked on the needed button, but what I got then was a new
>   page written fully in Korean. I don't read in Korean. I am sending a
>   screenshot of that page to you. ***Can you, please, help me as to
>   which button there I should choose now?*** Thank you.

Comment: Reads okay to me. :) -- (Though, I'd prefer an earlier sentence to read as *"I don't read Korean"*. Er, perhaps also *"Well, I clicked on that button"*.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase "as to which" is somewhat formal and "dated" ([this NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=as%20to%20which&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that it's being used less and less). In keeping with that observation, assuming OP stills want to use the phrase, a better way to put it would be...

> Can you please enlighten me as to which button...

Note that although the commas aren't exactly *incorrect*, they're certainly superfluous even with starchy phrasing such as this. A more modern/informal way of asking the question could be, for example...

> Can you please tell me which button...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it would be better if "as to" was replaced by a verb, such as "determine which."

*Can you, please, help me determine which button I should choose now?*

If "as to which" is used, it should be used more like this, although it's is a pretty cumbersome sentence:

*Can you please help me, as to the buttons, which I should choose now?*

Answer (score 0):

Can you please indicate the right button to click?
But,if you need to ask such a question on a website, you are on a wrong website, and, probably, you'll be getting a virus soon.